# Why does xcode fail to recognize the certificate associated with the provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, fastlane

I used fastlane match to generate certificates and provisioning profile for tvos app.
However in xcode under `Signing and Capabilities`, when the provisioning profile is selected, I am getting this error from xcode

> Provisioning profile "match AppStore com.x.x.x tvos" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution: XXX XXX XX (XXXXXXX)"

However, that certificate is installed in the keychain and is visible there and is selected in build settings `Signing` section.
The provisioning profile however is marked as ineligible when selecting. How can we fix this issue ?